# Need to remove rows and columns from dataframe using conditionals - How do I convert the following code from R to Python?

Tags: python, r, pandas, filter, boolean

I'm new to Python so I'm having trouble with syntax conversion from R.  The following R code identifies the mean of each row and column of the dataset and provides the boolean output for weak signals.

```
## Remove unregistered waps signals
weakWAPStrainCol <- apply(WAPStrainingData, 2, mean) >= 99.8
weakWAPStrainRow <- apply(WAPStrainingData, 1, mean) >= 99.8

goodWAPStrain <- WAPStrainingData[!weakWAPStrainRow,!weakWAPStrainCol]
goodWAPStrain
```

I was able to get the first part converted over to python but I can't figure out how to remove the rows and columns using the boolean variables.  Odds are it's something simple I'm overlooking.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Python Code:

```
# Remove unregistered WAPS signals
weakWAPStrainCol = [WAPStrainDat.mean(axis=0)>=99.8]
weakWAPStrainRow = [WAPStrainDat.mean(axis=1) >=99.8]
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` offer useful tools for data selection.

How about using `.loc` on a pandas.DataFrame object?

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(a=[1,2,3],b=[4,5,6]))
print(df)
bool_row = [True, True ,False]
bool_col = [False, True]
df.loc[bool_row,bool_col]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've tried df.loc and unfortunately, it still didn't work.  I got an IndexError: "Boolean index has wrong length: 1 instead of 19937"  I did find a round-about way of solving the problem but I don't feel it's all that efficient.  I'll post my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution but would still take any advice on making it more efficient.

R Code

```
## Remove unregistered waps signals
weakWAPStrainCol <- apply(WAPStrainingData, 2, mean) >= 99.8
weakWAPStrainRow <- apply(WAPStrainingData, 1, mean) >= 99.8

goodWAPStrain <- WAPStrainingData[!weakWAPStrainRow,!weakWAPStrainCol]
```

Python Code

```
# Remove unregistered WAPS signals
weakWAPStrainCol = [WAPStrainDat.mean(axis=0)>=99.8]
weakWAPStrainRow = [WAPStrainDat.mean(axis=1) >=99.8]
# Convert to DataFrame
weakWAPStrainCol_df = pd.DataFrame(weakWAPStrainCol)
weakWAPStrainRow_df = pd.DataFrame(weakWAPStrainRow).melt().drop(columns=['variable'])
# Inverse Boolean Values
weakWAPStrainCol_inv = ~weakWAPStrainCol_df
weakWAPStrainRow_inv = ~weakWAPStrainRow_df

# Create dataset with registered WAPS signals
goodWAPStrainRow = pd.concat([WAPStrainDat,weakWAPStrainRow_inv],axis=1)
goodWAPStrainCol = pd.concat([goodWAPStrainRow,weakWAPStrainCol_inv],axis=0)
goodWAPStrain = goodWAPStrainCol.loc[:,(goodWAPStrainCol == 1).any()]
goodWAPStrain = goodWAPStrain.loc[goodWAPStrain['value']==True]
goodWAPStrain
```